# Mouse and keyboard not working and no cursor on the desktop of Ubuntu 16.04 after installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptic`

Tags: keyboard, mouse, xserver, mouse-pointer

This happened when I installed the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptic` package, and it requested some packages to be removed.

As far as I remember, some of them contained `xserver`in their names.

What should I do?

Comment: do you mean you *uninstalled* `xserver-xorg-input-synaptic` rather than *installed* it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installed `xserver-xorg-input-all`package using `upstart` boot mode and it fixed the thing

Comment: Exactly works on Ubuntu 16.04 after update. It should be the correct answer!